# Go reflect field index - single index vs. slice

Tags: reflection, go

`reflect.StructField` has an `Index` field that is typed `[]int`.   The documentation on this is slightly confounding:

```
    Index     []int     // index sequence for Type.FieldByIndex
```

And of course `Type.FieldByIndex` follows suit as expected, with the somewhat clearer explanation of its behavior:

```
    // FieldByIndex returns the nested field corresponding
    // to the index sequence.  It is equivalent to calling Field
    // successively for each index i.
    // It panics if the type's Kind is not Struct.
    FieldByIndex(index []int) StructField
```

But, there is also `Type.Field()`:

```
    // Field returns a struct type's i'th field.
    // It panics if the type's Kind is not Struct.
    // It panics if i is not in the range [0, NumField()).
    Field(i int) StructFiel
```

So the behavior of those respectively is very clear.

My question:   Exactly for which fields / what circumstances will a `reflect.StructField` have an `Index` with `len(field.Index) > 1`?  Is this there to support enumerating embedded fields (reachable through an anonymous field in the parent)?  Does it happen in other cases?  (ie. is it  safe to assume if `!field.Anonymous`, then we can just use `field.Index[0]` as an argument to `Field(i int)`?)

Comment: ...`!field.Anonymous` or a field reachable only through an anonymous / embedded field, I suppose I should say.   Didn't consider at first the non-anonymous fields of the embedded struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was looking for the answer to this question, and I really haven't been able to find anything. To explain why the answer above is not satisfactory, I have an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type (
    A struct {
        W int
        X int
    }
    B struct {
        Y int
        A A
    }
    C struct {
        B B
        Z int
    }
)

func main() {
    b := B{1, A{2, 3}}
    c := C{b, 4}

    bt := reflect.TypeOf(b)
    ct := reflect.TypeOf(c)

    ba := bt.FieldByIndex([]int{1, 0})
    ca := ct.FieldByIndex([]int{0, 1, 0})

    fmt.Println("B > A = ", ba.Index)
    fmt.Println("C > B > A = ", ca.Index)
}
```

The output is:

> B > A =  [0]
> C > B > A =  [0]

So with the description of StructField.Index as is given in the docs (

> Index     []int     // index sequence for Type.FieldByIndex

) one would assume the output would correspond in some way to retrieving the same field via the `FieldByIndex` method, and since that is designed for nested fields, the output above might be confusing. If the `Index` is always an `[]int` of length 1, why even use an array? Why does it not store a single int if it is only in relation to its immediate parent?

The answer is probably simpler than we (those of us who found this confusing) expected. The `Index` value must often be used as an argument for `FieldByIndex`, and so it is stored in an array simply for convenience.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing that led me to ask originally.   In hindsight (7+ years of further Go development, wow!) I do think your explainer is correct.   But I can't really get into the minds of the Go authors, now a decade past.    I'll accept this anyhow, since I think it's the most valuable answer to this question here - or that this question is likely to get, ever, short of one of them stopping by.

Answer (score 5):

It can refer to fields in embedded or non embedded structs, recursively:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

type Baz struct {
    Zoo Foo
}

func main() {

    b := Baz{Zoo:Foo{"foo"}}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(b)

    fmt.Println(v.FieldByIndex([]int{0})) //output: <main.Foo Value>

    fmt.Println(v.FieldByIndex([]int{0, 0})) //output: foo

}
```

Comment: Thanks... as I said, though, the docs are clear and I understand what `FieldByIndex()` does.  My question is about the `Index` field of `reflect.StructField` - see the last two sentences of the question.

Comment: @BadZen I just gave you an example of how it's used for non embedded structs. But you should be fine with using a single index.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. To answer this question, I've dig into reflect tests.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type (
    Bar struct {
        Val string
    }

    Foo struct {
        Bar
    }
)

func main() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(Foo{})
    f, _ := t.FieldByName("Val")
    fmt.Println(f.Index)         // [0 0]
}
```